# FFMPEG, transcoding resolution error

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to convert a file using ffmpeg using the following command:

```
ffmpeg input.flv -strict experimental -s 360x288 output.3gp
```

I get the below error:

```
The specified picture size of 360x288 is not valid for the H.263 codec.
Valid sizes are 128x96, 176x144, 352x288, 704x576, and 1408x1152. Try H.263+
```

The problem here is that i don't use a command line to execute the commands, but through another program that I am coding,

So if I am to only use the above specified resolutions, is there a command for ffmepeg so that given a codec, to retrieve the possible resolutions so that I can select the optimal one to convert with, not just for the above codec, but all codecs supported by ffmpeg.

I have seen the documentation page of ffmpeg and the supported video resolutions but that is not what I am looking for, that is the resolutions that ffmpeg supports, not the resolutions the codec supports,

I am looking for a command that will give me the resolutions that a given code will support

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are asking about resolution only, yes that's all.

H263 supports specific resolution only. other codecs does not depends on resolution.

sadly, there is no such lists which show available options with matched codec. you should search, try one by one :)

there are more things in audio codecs. such as bit rate, channel layout, and sample rate.

but only h263 codec does depend on specific resolution.